# How to get split tabs in Microsoft Edge extensions?

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have working code to get normal tabs and their IDs in my Microsoft Edge extension, but Edge has this new Split-tab feature, and it seams my code can't see the right side "tab", only the left side.

```
// Get all tabs that match the pattern
const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({
  url: [
    "https://url.of.website/*"
  ],
});
```

I can't seam to find the API documentation related Microsoft Edge, if there is any. As this is 404 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/supported-apis/

Comment: As far as I know, extensions in Edge uses the same API as in chrome. Just refer to this doc: [Supported APIs for Microsoft Edge extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support). But I didn't find a description of the split function in the tabs API documentation. Can you describe your needs more clearly?

Comment: Hey @XudongPeng, so I have an extension which injects some CSS into the tabs based on their URLs.

I can confirm that it works like a charm with active/inactive tabs being all returned and iterateable when there is no-split tabs in use.

I can even confirm that when I split, and select an existing tab to be on right side, the TabID stays the same. 

But the JavaScript query stops returning this right-side-split tab and it basically becomes invisible to the extension. 

Content Script is still executed at page reload, but the popup.js can't see it anymore.

Comment: Well, I think what you mean is the split-screen feature in Edge, and I found that the problem you mentioned has been raised here, and it seems that the problem has not been solved yet. I think you could also send feedback to the relevant team on this issue. Just press `Alt+Shift+I` to edit your issue and send it. Thank you for your understanding.